# What does INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES package type mean in the FedEx API?

Tags: fedex

I've called FedEx Web Services twice (they don't know and keep failing to escalate my ticket) and searched all the manuals. It's not defined anywhere that I can find.

We are trying to understand whether we need to use YOUR_PACKAGING or INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES. It's fair to say both sound very similar to someone just learning the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOUR_PACKAGING is used as a packaging type when the parcel is packaged in non-FedEx packaging. The other possible packaging types are:

- FEDEX_10KG_BOX
- FEDEX_25KG_BOX
- FEDEX_BOX
- FEDEX_ENVELOPE
- FEDEX_EXTRA_LARGE_BOX
- FEDEX_LARGE_BOX
- FEDEX_MEDIUM_BOX
- FEDEX_PAK
- FEDEX_SMALL_BOX
- FEDEX_TUBE

The documentation does not specify what INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES means, but it's not used for specifying the packaging type.